# EWS - Office 365 - "One or more subscriptions in the request reside on another Client Access server."

Tags: exchangewebservices, office365

My goal is to subscribe for streaming notifications for multiple users in the same time.

One way to do that is to create multiple  **StreamingSubscriptionConnections** each one should contain one  **StreamingSubscription** for each user. The problem with this method is that in Office 365 the maximum number of connections opened is 20.

Another method to solve this problem is by creating one **StreamingSubscriptionConnection** and then all **StreamingSubscriptions** for each user to the connection. This method solves the maximum number of connections problem and it works fine with exchange onPrimises. But when trying it with Office 365 it will result with the SubscriptionError:

> "One or more subscriptions in the request reside on another Client
>   Access server. GetStreamingEvents won't proxy in the event of a batch
>   request."

Can anyone help me here ?

Comment: Have you seen this article about grouping your subscriptions? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn458789(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: Yes but for some reason I was not able to get the "GroupingInformation " property

Comment: Are you using Autodiscover? And are you targeting an Exchange 2013 or Exchange Online? I'm pretty sure GroupingInformation was added in Exchange 2013, so if you're targeting a previous version, you won't get it.

Comment: When I initiate an instance (AutodiscoverService) I assigned to 2013
But when I want to used the method "GetUserSettings()" , the first parameter is the userSmtp , and the second one is the name of setting I want to get. But I do not get the "GroupingInformation" as an option in the Enum list. 
autodiscoverService.GetUserSettings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to the latest version of the EWS Managed API, version 2.1. It has GroupingInformation added to the enumeration. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42022

Comment: I did not try it yet , but if it works then thank you so much :)

Comment: I already am at 2.1 but this doesn't work for me. My code works on our own Exchange 2013 server, but since we want to switch to office 365 I need this to work. I have a connection and it says I am connected to two "subscribers', but then it throws the same error as @BraveHeart experiences. Any new thoughts on this?